# How can I get rid of extra user profiles in user profiles in Central administration?

Tags: user-profile, synchronization

I've imported extra containers from active directory like service accounts and disabled accounts and Number of User Profiles is 1539, I know the number of employees in my organization is about 1200, I tried to Edit synchronization connection and bring in ONLY the containers that I need and start full synchronization again, But it still shows 1539 for Number of User Profiles. How can I get rid of extra user profiles?

Thanks,

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Use [Set-SPProfileServiceApplication](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff608004.aspx).

```
$sa = Get-SPServiceApplication | ?{$_.TypeName -match "Profile"}
Set-SPProfileServiceApplication -Identity $sa -PurgeNonImportedObjects $true
```